# Create tbody with collapsed (parent/child) rows

Tags: knockout.js, parent-child

I have a `tbody` table with parent-child structure backed by knockout view models. The parent-child structure looks like this:

```html
<tbody>
    <!-- ko foreach: modelyears -->
        <tr>
            <td >
                <span data-bind="text: modelyear_name"></span>
            </td>
            <td>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <!-- ko foreach: projects -->
            <tr>
                <td >
                </td>
                <td>
                    <span data-bind="text: project_name"></span>
                </td>
            </tr>
        <!-- /ko -->
    <!-- /ko -->
</tbody>
```

How can I make the parent row expandable/collapsable?

I want to click on the parent `tr` to show/hide the child rows (projects).

Comment: code looks fine . all you need is to inject some bootstrap expand/collapse into it .

Comment: @supercool Not sure if introducing Bootstrap just for a collapse/expand is quite needed, a handcrafted one will also do. Do agree with the underlying message though: the post is more a to-do than a question.

Comment: @Jeroen yup a handcrafted will do #agreed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it by myself with bootstrap "collapse" functionality.

The "data-target" is a binding to knockout computed value, which I get from the ITEM ID of the current parent.

Here is the code in HTML ( I used DIV for parent-child representation and a hyperlink attribute to toggle the childs ):

```html
            
<!-- ko foreach: modelyears -->
<div>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td >
                <a  href="#" data-toggle="collapse" data-bind="attr: {'id': child_id, 'data-target' : data_target }">
                    <span data-bind="text: modelyear_name" ></span>
                </a>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
<!-- ko foreach: projects -->
<div data-bind="css: project_classname">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td colspan="2">
                <div>
                    <span data-bind="text: project_name"></span>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
<!-- /ko -->
<!-- /ko -->undefined</div>
```

The knockout variables "child_id" and "data-target" and "project_classname" where computed in the knockout model:

```js
// compute "project_classname"
this.project_classname = ko.computed(function() {
   return "collapse row" + self.project_modelyear_itemid();
}, this);

// compute "child_id"
this.child_id = ko.computed(function ()
{
  return "row" + self.modelyear_itemid();
}, this);

// compute "data_target"
this.data_target = ko.computed(function ()
{
return ".row" + self.modelyear_itemid();
}, this);
```

Answer (score 1):

As supper cool pointed out, the best solution is to use some UI effect that allows you to expand in a more fashionable way. However, the simple solution is to maintain a boolean value, indicating whether the modelyear is expanded or not:

```
<tbody>
    <!-- ko foreach: modelyears -->
        <tr data-bind="click: expandClose">
            <td >
                <span data-bind="text: modelyear_name"></span>
            </td>
            <td>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <!-- ko foreach: projects -->
            <tr data-bind="if: $parent.isExpanded">
                <td >
                </td>
                <td>
                    <span data-bind="text: project_name"></span>
                </td>
            </tr>
        <!-- /ko -->
    <!-- /ko -->
</tbody>
```

expandClose just switch between true/false on the isExpanded property of your modelyear object (this has to be ko.observable). With this, knockout will add/remove the elements to the DOM as long as this property is true/false. You can also use **visible** instead of **if**. The difference is that **visible** renders once, and then switch between display/display:none, whilst **if** re-renders. Note: check syntax, as I have not tested this code.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, another cool and easy ( !) solution.. :)